# Background Image Troubleshooting

Tags: image

Why isn't my background jpg. image showing up in this instance, have I missed a setting somewhere?

I have [image]included a screenshot below and It should be showing up in the right Ortho view as far as I know.

What I have tried so far,

1. When I import an image, or drag and drop an image into blender to use as a background reference image, it does not immediately show up in the view port I am trying to put it into. With the axis preference setting set to all views in the properties menu. It usually default drops the image into the Top Ortho view where I cant immediately see it. I can usually only see it after I cycle through the keypad and/or play with the properties settings axis setting it to a specific view such as Top or right ect.. Other times when I drag and drop it into a user perspective window , it does not show up in the Top Ortho, but the Right Ortho. I realize that it does not show in any of the perspective views because the load background feature (located in the properties panel) only works in Otho view ports.
2. I have tried to see if it was a corrupt file, the file checks out OK in other viewing editors, file attached below.
3. I have navigated through the different view port views, such as perspective vs. Otho view, and also camera view. I have also tried to view it from the Quad view (picture inserted below) as opposed to a single view with the same results.

4.I also tried playing with the transparency slider and the view as render tick box.

5. I have also looked through a few other similar posts and tried the solutions suggested in searching for a solution. Although insightful, no solution was suggested that worked.

The solutions and walk throughs I have already tried are posted below.

Thank you in advance. Any thoughts, resources, or further suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[Background image not showing up in any 3-D view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23651/background-image-not-showing-up-in-any-3-d-view)

and also

[Background images not showing up at all in persp or ortho view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50384/background-images-not-showing-up-at-all-in-persp-or-ortho-view)

and this one to

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?260731-Background-Image-not-showing-up

[image]

If I open blender up new, then load the same image. It will work in the Right Ortho View as it should and seems to function correctly. However, if I open it up in the previous file with my objects as shown in the previous screen shot, then this image will not load. The only difference I could see between the 2 blend files is that one has a few more mesh objects in it and a couple of key frames inserted into the time line. I have inserted the image below with the jpeg functioning correctly.
[image]

Comment: Mabe it's a bug.. By default it should work in all preset ortho views + camera view if drag-and-dropping image into the 3D Viewport. Do other images work in that .blend file ? Is it possible to preview background image in other files ?